# Photoshop CS4 color fill mask layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to make the same color fill layer (if correct term) to the attached image so rendering color of a graphic element is simpler without the color overlay effect.

If I click the solid color button placed at the bottom of the layer window it gives me a new layer with a color fill but it's not masked.

### [image: color fill mask]

**Added**

What I want to achieve is making it easy for color adjustment for every graphic element exactly how the attached image demonstrates. I was unsure whether it was a vector or raster element. Now I know that drawing a vector shape will automatically give me the color fill mask so I am happy with my finding. I was rushing a bit when I posted this question.

[image: solid color button]

Comment: I don't understand this at all. What "color button"? I'm not aware of any such button.

Comment: @Scott Please see my added screenshot. You will see `solid color...` on the top.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? It's clear that you want to mask the 'solid color' layer, but can you explain a bit more what you want to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: The icon you have circled is the Adjustment **layer** icon which creates an adjustment layer. I'm sorry but your question is simply not clear at all.

Answer (score 2):

And there's a few ways of doing it, and here's a couple:

**Method 1**

Create your `Solid Color Adjustment Layer`, `right-click` it and select `Create Clipping Mask`

[image]

**Method 2**

`CTRL-Click` the thumbnail of the layer you want to put the mask over,

[image]

This will create a selection of that layer. Now create your `Solid Color Adjustment Layer` and the mask will automatically be applied.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I just found that color fill mask is automatically generated when using vector shape tool.

[image]